# Importing a list of vertices in to blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I have a list of vertices in a file in the following format, where each line contains the x, y and z coordinates of a vertex.

```
0.2 0.2 -0.5
0.7 0.8 -0.2
0.8 0.1 -0.8
```

How can I import this in to Blender without writing my own tool to convert to a file format like Wavefront .obj? Or is there a tool which could do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

To get a valid file in `.obj` format, each line (vertex) needs to include `v`  before the coordinates.

One easy way to do this is to use `sed`, for example this command, given that your current file is `file.txt`

```
sed 's/^/v /' file.txt  > new-file.obj
```

After this, you should be able to import the file in Blender as a Wavefront obj.